# Inconsistencies in Big-O of removing from an ArrayList vs a Hash Table?

Tags: java, data-structures, computer-science, time-complexity

I'm looking at [this website](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) that lists Big O complexities for various operations.  For Dynamic Arrays, the removal complexity is O(n), while for Hash Tables it's O(1).

For Dynamic Arrays like ArrayLists to be O(n), that must mean the operation of removing some value from the center and then shifting each index over one to keep the block of data contiguous.  Because if we're just deleting the value stored at index k and not shifting, it's O(1).

But in Hash Tables with linear probing, deletion is the same thing, you just run your value through the Hash function, go to the Dynamic Array holding your data, and delete the value stored in it.

So why do Hash Tables get O(1) credit while Dynamic Arrays get O(n)?

Comment: Why should they be 'consistent'? Have you considered the possibility that your assumptions are incorrect?

Comment: I suggest you remove the [tag:java] tag, and mentions of ArrayList, and replace it by [tag:language-agnostic] if you really want, but just [tag:data-structures] is also fine, unless this question is specifically about the Java API's hash table implementation (note that that doesn't use linear probing, it uses separate chaining, as [Stephen pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20515146/1711796)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Performance_analysis). The key is that the number of values per Dynamic Array is kept under a constant value.

Edit: As Dukeling pointed out, my answer explains why a Hash Table with *separate chaining* has O(1) removal complexity. I should add that, on the website you were looking at, Hash Tables are credited with O(1) removal complexity because they analyse a Hash Table with separate chaining and not linear probing.

Comment: The question asks about linear probing, not separate chaining. Well, I'm assuming you're talking about separate chaining, otherwise what you said doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The point of hash tables is that they keep close to the best case, where the best case means a single entry per bucket. Clearly, you have no trouble accepting that to remove the sole entry from a bucket takes O(1) time.

Comment: It's difficult to tell whether you're talking about linear probing or separate chaining (it *seems* to be separate chaining, but on the other hand, it sort of makes sense if it's linear probing as well). The question asks about linear probing. I thought I'd just point that out.

Comment: I'm talking about both. Since linear probing has nothing to do with `HashMap`, I assumed OP doesn't care about the detailed distinction.

Answer (score 1):

When there are many hash conflicts, you certainly need to do a lot of shifting when using linear probing.

But the complexity for hash tables are under the assumption of [Simply Uniform Hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUHA_%28computer_science%29), meaning that it assumes that there will be a minimal number of hash conflicts.

When this happens, we only need to delete some value and shift either no values or a small (essentially constant) amount of values.

Answer (score 0):

When you talk about the complexity of an algorithm, you actually need to discuss a concrete implementation.

- There is no Java class called a "Hash Table" (obviously!) or "HashTable".
- There are Java classes called `HashMap` and `Hashtable`, and these do indeed have `O(1)` deletion.

But they don't work the way that you seem to think (all?) hash tables work. Specifically, `HashMap` and `Hashtable` are organized as an array of pointers to "chains".

This means that deletion consists of finding the appropriate chain, and then traversing the chain to find the entry to remove.  The first step is constant time (including the time to calculate the hash code.  The second step is proportional to the length of the hash chains.  But assuming that the hash function is good, the average length of the hash chain is a small constant.  Hence the total time for deletion is O(1) on average.

---

<sup>The reason that the hash chains are short on average is that the `HashMap` and `Hashtable` classes automatically resize the main hash array when the "load factor" (the ratio of the array size to the number of entries) exceeds a predetermined value.  Assuming that the hash function distributes the (actual) keys pretty evenly, you will find that the chains are roughly the same length.  Assuming that the array size is proportional to the total number of entries, the actual load factor will the average hash chain length.</sup>

<sup>This reasoning breaks down if the hash function does not distribute the keys evenly.  This leads to a situation where you get a lot of *hash collisions*.  Indeed, the worst-case behaviour is when all keys have the same hash value, and they all end up on a single hash chain with all N entries.  In that case, deletion involves searching a chain with N entries ... and that makes it `O(N)`.</sup>

---

It turns out that the same reasoning can be applied to other forms of hash table, including those where the entries are stored in the hash array itself, and collisions are handled by rehashing scanning.  (Once again, the "trick" is to expand the hash table when the load factor gets too high.)

Comment: Java classes also can't contain spaces, so my thoughts are that OP wasn't actually talking a Java class, but just hash tables in general, with linear probing (which was explicitly mentioned), rather than just having made a typing error, and not knowing that the Java class doesn't use linear probing.